# Non-Ubuntu oriented pygame platformer not loading levels correctly on anything other than Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, pygame, cross-platform, compatibility

I've been working on a `pygame` platformer, based on [this](https://codepaste.net/to4vrn). I wrote it on an Ubuntu machine, and it doesn't seem to work on other operating systems.

The generation code is something like this:

```
levelFile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r', defaultextension='.lvl', filetypes=[('Level File', '*.lvl')], parent=tk)
level = levelFile.read().split("\n")
del level[len(level) - 1]

# Add platforms to array based on level string
```

I made a level in a text editor using ASCII characters to represent different tiles.

It works fine on my Ubuntu machine, but when run on a MacBook Air and a Windows laptop, it doesn't. The level layout doesn't load as expected (the tiles load in unexpected places, and the camera position is messed up).

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the levels don't generate correctly"?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means don't drop 335 lines of code and expect us to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line separators in your level file are OS-dependent if you create your file under linux it will use "\n" under windows "\r\n", so this could be a reason why it is not working. i think you should use os.linesep instead of "\n" to split the file into lines.

```
level = levelFile.read().split(os.linesep)
```